# github folder unclickable

Tags: git, github

My components folder is unclickable in my github repository. It's an unclickable blue folder.

What to do? And what is the reasoning for it being unclickable?

Picture of problem:

[image: Picture of problem]

Comment: I think it’s a symlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a nested Git rpeository, which means the parent repo has only recorded the root folder SHA1 (called "gitlink"), but not (like a git submodule) the remote repo URL.

You should remove the folder entry with:

```
# no trailing /
git rm --cached -- components
git commit -m "remove components entry"
git push
```

Comment: You are the savior!